# modifying main menu of jupyter lab

Tags: css, typescript, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions

I'm trying to modify the main menu of jupyter lab through jupyterlab extension. What I want to do is to remove or collapse all tabs into one. As I didn't find any explanation on that I tried to follow a tutorial to work with menu tabs: https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-examples/tree/master/main-menu

However, I'm not being able to reproduce it. I run these commands on the terminal (inside the main-menu folder):

```
python -m pip install -e .

# install your development version of the extension with JupyterLab
jupyter labextension develop . --overwrite

# build the TypeScript source after making changes
jlpm run build

# start JupyterLab
jupyter lab
```

But the "Main Menu Example" tab never appears.

What could it be? some cache information that I need to clean?

Comment: Similar issue was discussed [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/building-extension-has-no-effect/9968?u=fomightez). Maybe some of the suggestions there would help you sort this?

Comment: Also see the February 16th thread started by Simran Gupta at https://gitter.im/jupyterlab/jupyterlab